# GLES program resources index/location vs uniform index/location

Tags: c++, opengl-es

In OpenGL ES 3.2, there are functions such as

```
//for simplify I omit the params
GLuint glGetProgramResourceIndex(...);
void glGetProgramResourceiv(...);
GLint glGetProgramResourceLocation(...);
```

to query the index of a named resource within a program, to retrieve values for multiple properties of a single active resource with an index of index, to query location of a named resource within a program.

And there are functions such as:

```
void glGetUniformIndices(...);
GLuint glGetUniformBlockIndex(...);
GLint glGetUniformLocation(...);
```

to retrieve the index of a named uniform block, to retrieve the location of a uniform variable.

Thanks to @Nicol Bolas, I already know the difference between uniform location and uniform index by this question [Difference between uniform location and uniform index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302276/difference-between-uniform-location-and-uniform-index)

But what's the relationship between the `program resources index/location` and the `uniform index/location`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older OpenGL versions (before 4.3), there were several different API calls to identify resources of a shader, for example, `glGetActiveAttrib` for attributes, `glGetActiveUniform*` for uniforms or `glGetActiveSubroutine*` for subroutines.

In OpenGL 4.3 a unified way of querying these ressources was introduces through the `ARB_program_interface_query` extension. With these commands you can do basically the same thing (or a bit more) as with the above mentioned functions but without having to use a different method for every resource type.

[This page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection) has more information on the topic.

Comment: So, they are just same identifies of resources but get from different API? Will a program resource location retrieved by `glGetProgramResourceLocation` of a uniform variable `x` equal to the uniform location retrieved by `glGetUniformLocation` of the same uniform variable?

Comment: A location: Yes. For the index I'm not sure

Comment: I think the index is same too. I found that in section 7.6 Uniform Variables of [OpenGL ES 3.2 Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/es_spec_3.2.pdf). Really thanks for your answer and comments!